# Concatenation of regular languages

Tags: regex, complexity-theory, regular-language

Suppose we have two language

```
L = {0^n|n>=0}
M = {1^n|n>=0}
```

We know both of these are regular languages.

Will L.M (concatenation) be a regular language?
Please explain your answer and if yes then what will be its expression?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on cs.stackexchange.com or cstheory.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Adding to it, we know that language {o^n1^n|n>=0} isn't a regular language.

Comment: @Mcolorz, that is neither here or there.  That language is not the concatenation of L and M.

Comment: @Mcolorz yes L.M is regular. I think you are confused because it may seem like `{a^nb^n | n >=0}` to you (that is CF) but it is NOT like that. Instead L.M  is like `{a^nb^m | n, m >=0}` that is Regular.